# Recipe to determine symmetries of quadratic fermionic Hamiltonian in second quantisation

Tags: symmetry, topology, second-quantization, topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry

Consider an arbitrary 1D chain (of length $N$) of fermions with an arbitrary quadratic Hamiltonian of the form

$$\mathcal{H}=\hat{\Psi}^\dagger H \hat{\Psi}$$

with

$$\hat{\Psi}=\left(a_1, a_2, ...,a_N,a_1^\dagger, a_2^\dagger, ...,a_N^\dagger \right)^T$$

a vector of fermionic operators where $a_n^\dagger$ creates a fermion at site $n$.

Are there some straight forward recipes for determining whether the Hamiltonian has any symmetries, specifically chiral, time-reversal, and particle-hole symmetry etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the eyeball technique: the form of $\hat{\Psi}$ suggests that you express the single particle hamiltonian $H$ as a $2 \times 2$-block operator and look for relations between the blocks. Hence, start with complex conjugation, the three Pauli matrices and products of Pauli matrices and complex conjugation.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But how specifically do I relate complex conjugation and the Pauli matrices to symmetry operators?

Comment: These are natural candidates for your symmetries, because they naturally square to $\pm 1$ and give relations between $a_j$ and $a_j^{\dagger}$.

Comment: Thank you, but I still do not understand how to make symmetry operators out of them

Comment: You have 3 Pauli matrices and complex conjugation, which gives you 7 candidates for discrete symmetries. Given a hamiltonian, you need to see which, if any, (anti)commutes. In practice it is easier to compute $U H U^{-1}$ and compare that to $\pm H$. Conversely, if you are looking for a hamiltonian with particular symmetries (or that breaks particular symmetries), you select the candidates (e. g. an odd antiunitary). Then comparing $U H U^{-1}$ to $\pm H$ gives relations between the four block operators. This allows you to pick a model that preserves or breaks the relevant symmetries.

Comment: Thanks again, but I still do not understand how this relates to the *symmetries* of the system. Ok so I can form some $U$ that is some combination of the Pauli matrices, but what actually *is* it. What does it *represent*

Comment: i.e. what combination of my basis matrices corresponds to time-reversal symmetry, which to chirality etc.

Comment: Time-reversal symmetries are antiunitaries which commute with $H$; particle-hole-type symmetries are antiunitaries which anticommute with $H$. The antiunitary symmetries come in an even and an odd variety, depending on whether they square to $\pm \mathbf{1}$. So all of the four antiunitary operators are candidates for time-reversal or particle-hole symmetries, and their nature depends on the hamiltonian. E. g. it is false that complex conjugation always physically corresponds to time-reversal. The three unitary symmetries can either be ordinary (commuting) or chiral (anticommuting) symmetries.